# How to extract the property values of a object into an array and make elements in the array different？

Tags: javascript

i got this array

```
var data = [
    {F: 'a', T: 'z', V:1},
    {F: 'b', T: 'z', V:2},
    {F: 'c', T: 'z', V:3}
]
```

and i want got this array below 
I used method forEach

```
 var nodes = [];
 data.forEach(function(element) {
   nodes.push({name:element.F})
   nodes.push({name:element.T}            
 })
```

but got a repetitive element{name:'z'} in array but  don't want the repetitive element ,I want the array below

```
[
    {name:'a'},
    {name:'b'},
    {name:'c'},
    {name:'z'},
]
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: what script you have written that gives repetitive element?

Comment: how do you filter the keys? by type?

Comment: i already edited my question and codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()` functions:

```js
var data = [{F: 'a', T: 'z', V:1}, {F: 'b', T: 'z', V:2}, {F: 'c', T: 'z', V:3}],

    result = data.reduce(function (a, o) {  // getting an array of unique values
        if (a.indexOf(o.F) === -1) a.push(o.F);
        if (a.indexOf(o.T) === -1) a.push(o.T);
        return a;
    }, [])
        .map(function (v) { return {name: v}; });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create new `Set` and then add values of `F` and `T` and then transform that set to array and use `map()`.

```js
var data = [{F: 'a', T: 'z', V:1},{F: 'b', T: 'z', V:2},{F: 'c', T: 'z', V:3}]

var set = new Set()
data.forEach(function(e) {
  if(e.F) set.add(e.F)
  if(e.T) set.add(e.T)
})

var result = [...set].map(e => ({name: e}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and push only values which are not in the hash table.

```js
var data = [{ F: 'a', T: 'z', V: 1 }, { F: 'b', T: 'z', V: 2 }, { F: 'c', T: 'z', V: 3 }],
    nodes = [],
    hash = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function(element) {
    ['F', 'T'].forEach(function (k) {
        hash[element[k]] || nodes.push({ name: element[k] });
        hash[element[k]] = true;
    });
});

nodes.sort(function (a, b) { return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); });
console.log(nodes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using unique key object capability (only if initial your object value (here data) are stringable) (no if in the code) :

```js
var data = [{ F: 'a', T: 'z', V: 1 }, { F: 'b', T: 'z', V: 2 }, { F: 'c', T: 'z', V: 3 }];

var result = Object.keys(
    data.reduce( (memo, el) => { 
        memo[el.F] = undefined; 
        memo[el.T] = undefined; 
        return memo; 
    }, {})
).reduce( (memo, el) => { 
    memo.push({name: el}); 
    return memo; 
}, []);

console.log(result)
```